# Replace string with jQuery

Tags: replace, escaping, str-replace

I´d like to replace all fraction in my HTML code:
1/2 => ½ `&frac12;`
1/4 => ¼ `&frac14;`
... all fraction.

I try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var strNewString = $('body').html().replace(/\1/2/g,'&frac12;');
    $('body').html(strNewString);
}); // END jQuery document ready
```

It doesn´t work for me. I need some help, should be an escaping issue, or?
Or can I use a jQuery Plugin for smarter glyphs and special typo characters?

Thanks
Ogni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me ;-) yes, it was a escaping issue!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var strNewString = $('body').html().replace(/1\/2/g,'&frac12;');
$('body').html(strNewString);
}); // END jQuery document ready
```

Comment: @ogni You can easily make this more generic, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could also match a more generic solution using the the digit class and capture groups in regular expressions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fractionMatcher = /(\d+)\/(\d+)/g;
    var strNewString = $('body').html()
                       .replace(fractionMatcher,'<sup>$1</sup> &frasl; <sub>$2</sub>');
    $('body').html(strNewString);
}); // END jQuery document ready
```

Here is a fiddle that shows it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/9brEw/1/

It isn't exactly the same fraction symbols you show above, but it can match arbitrary fractions (not just 1/2, 1/4, etc...).